# Is infrastructure testing on-topic on SQA?

Tags: discussion

Are the questions on configuration and infrastructure testing on topic on SQA?

For example questions related to tools like: [Serverspec](http://serverspec.org/), [Chef InSpec](https://www.chef.io/inspec/), [Molecule](https://github.com/metacloud/molecule), [KitchenCI](http://kitchen.ci/).

*Such questions are rather rare even on StackOverflow, but literally non-existent here, hence the question.*

Answer (score 1):

Good question, a lot of of it is indeed borderline and can be answered elsewhere.

The experimental devops stackexchange will complicate things even more since it is even closer.

Unfortunately I think this should be handled on a case by case basis, I can't think of a generic way to filter such questions

Comment: To summarize, we haven't seen a lot of infrastructure questions but we believe at least some of them belong here.